# Choose one particular row per group?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called ratings that looks like this

> ```
> Rating   |   Picid    |   User
>    8           12          6
>    7           12          6
>    9           15          7
>    5           16          7
>    9           17          8
>    10          2           8
>    7           18          3
>    10          22          12
> ```

I want to group the ratings based on the picid, but only choose the highest rated picid per user. I have the query like this already:

```
SELECT *, AVG(rating) AS total FROM ratings
  GROUP BY picid ORDER by total DESC
```

Right now the query would output the information like this:

> ```
> Rating   |   Picid    |   User
>  7.5           12          6
>    9           15          7
>    5           16          7
>    9           17          8
>    10          2           8
>    7           18          3
>    10          22          12
> ```

So it successfully groups the ratings based on the picid, but I want only the ONE highest per user. I want it to output information like this:

> ```
> Rating   |   Picid    |   User
>  7.5           12          6
>    9           15          7
>    10          2           8
>    7           18          3
>    10          22          12
> ```

See how it only allows the highest rated picid per user? 
How can I modify my query to do this?

Let me know if you need more clarification on what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first must calculate the average ratings for each `(Picid,User)` combination, then find the [group-wise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) over that materialised result:

```
SELECT Rating, PicID, User
FROM (
  SELECT   AVG(Rating) AS Rating, Picid, User
  FROM     ratings
  GROUP BY Picid, User
) t1 NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   MAX(Rating) AS Rating, User
  FROM     (
    SELECT   AVG(Rating) AS Rating, User
    FROM     ratings
    GROUP BY Picid, User
  ) t
  GROUP BY User
) t2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60a4b/21).

Comment: This seems good. But I have to admit that the `NATURAL` joins add to my confusion :)

Comment: it's not MySQL specific. It's in the SQL standard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best way, but it works:

```
SELECT MAX(total) as maxTotal, picid, User 
FROM 
   (SELECT *, AVG(rating) AS total 
    FROM ratings 
    GROUP BY picid 
    ORDER BY total DESC) as a 
GROUP BY User 
ORDER BY maxTotal desc;
```

You can use this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b42/9) to try others.

Comment: Yey, [it works on my machine!](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/06/it-works-on-my-machine-award/)

Comment: Watch out for the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting when not providing the all the non-aggregate columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What happens if the same pic has been rated by multiple users?